# Run JavaScript function after window load, including any asynchronous downloads

Tags: javascript, load, webfonts

I have an `initialise` function in my app that I want to trigger when two conditions have been met: 1) the window has loaded: `$(window).load()` and 2) Typekit has loaded.

```
$(window).load(function() {
    try {
        Typekit.load({ active: initialise });
    } catch (e) {}
});
```

At the moment, this code is waiting until the window has loaded (including all resources e.g. images) before it starts to load the Typekit web fonts, and then, when they have loaded too, it will initialise.

However, I want Typekit to load before the window has loaded. They should load asynchronously. So:

```
$(window).load(initialise);

try {
    Typekit.load({ active: initialise });
} catch (e) {}
```

Now the Web fonts are loading asynchronously, but the problem is, I need the `initialise` function to trigger only when both 1) the window has loaded: `$(window).load()` and 2) Typekit has loaded. Sometimes, the window will load before Typekit has loaded, and sometimes it is the other way round.

So my question is: how can I trigger `initialise` as soon as both of my criteria have been fulfilled?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution that uses jQuery's `$.holdReady`:

```
$.holdReady(true);

Typekit.load({
    active: function () {
        $.holdReady(false);
    }
});

$window.load(function () {
    $document.ready(initialize);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Increment and test at each event.  Once `ready` is positive, `initialize` will fire:

```
   {
        var ready = -1;
        $(window).load(function() {
            if (++ready) initialize();
        });

        try {
            Typekit.load({
                active: function() {
                    if (++ready) initialize();
                }
            });
        } catch (e) {}

        function initialize() {
            //do work
        }
    }
```

Comment: This is a great solution. Not sure whether to use this or the example/answer I just posted that uses jQuery's `$.holdReady`. Performance wise, I would take a guess this is better.

Comment: Why the weird `++` construction? It's JavaScript, not C ;) Other than that, this solution is fine. `$.holdReady` is just as good. Performance doesn't matter in this case. It probably makes some microseconds of a difference.

Comment: @Pumbaa80, I don't understand your question.  `++` is a standard operator and `++ready` is the valid increment here.

Answer (score 0):

`load()` ist not the correct method to trigger when window has loaded. It's [`ready()`](http://api.jquery.com/ready/).

```
Typekit.load({
    active: function () {
        $(document).ready(initialize);
    }
});
```

The `ready()` method will run the callback immediately if the window is already loaded. The `load()` method binds an event handler to the `load` DOM event, which at that moment has already fired. Thus the handler never gets called.

Comment: I believe I need to use `load()` because that includes image downloads, which is something I require to have downloaded before executing my `initialise` function.

Comment: So I tried what you said but changed it to `$(window).load(initialise)`. Unfortunately it seems that the method does not run the callback immediately if the window has already loaded, unlike `ready()`.

Answer (score -1):

You can use a setInterval and check two variables which will be set

```
var windowLoaded = false, typeKitLoaded = false, myLoadedInterval = null;
$(window).load(function() { windowLoaded = true; if ( myLoadedInterval == null ) beginInterval(); });
try {
    Typekit.load({ active: function() { typeKitLoaded = true; if ( myLoadedInterval == null ) beginInterval(); } });
} catch (e) {}

function beginInterval()
{
    myLoadedInterval = setInterval(function() {
        if ( typeKitLoaded && windowLoaded ) 
        {
            clearInterval(myLoadedInterval);
            initialise();
        } 
    }, 25);
}
```